# Hide area name for single controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I'm pretty new to Areas and Url Routing in MVC so I'm not sure what I need to do here to get the result that I am looking for.

I have an area called `Policy`, inside that area I have three controllers: `PolicyController`, `GroupController` and `SectionController`.

The problem with this is when I want to for example go to the detail of a policy the url looks like: `http://www.example.com/Policy/Policy/Detail/1` but instead I would like it to look like: `http://www.example.com/Policy/Detail/1`

I've seen a few examples on how to hide the Area completely from the URL but that's not what I would like to do. As I would still like to see `http://www.example.com/Policy/Group/Index` or `http://www.example.com/Policy/Section/Index`

So in other words, I would only like to hide the Area name when I am using the controller that has the same name as the area.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: What does your RouteConfig.cs look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a default controller as an entry point in your area, but you can not skip controller name on routing. Otherwise you would have to create a default route for each action in the Policy Controller:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    // Entry point for each action on Policy controller
    context.MapRoute(
        "Policy_default_detail",
        "Policy/Detail/{id}",
        new { controller = "Policy", action = "Detail", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    context.MapRoute(
        "Policy_default_anotheraction",
        "Policy/AnotherAction/{id}",
        new { controller = "Policy", action = "AnotherAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );


    // Default entry point
    context.MapRoute(
        "Policy_default",
        "Policy/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

The downside of this design is that you could not have a controller with the same name of an action on Policy controller.

I suggest you rethink areas naming, so that the name of the area do not match the names of the controllers.

Comment: This works perfectly for what I am trying to do in this project. In future projects I will be sure to think of different names for the Areas so I don't have this conflict. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a specific route definition in your area registration class before the generic area registration code.

```
public class PolicyAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {

        context.MapRoute(
            "Policy_Tricky",
            "Policy/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "Policy", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           new string[] { "YourProjectName.Areas.Policy.Controllers" }
        );


        context.MapRoute(
            "Policy_default",
            "Policy/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           new string[] { "YourProjectName.Areas.Policy.Controllers" }
           //Providing namespace while defining route to prevent conflict 
        );
    }
}
```